# "If only to do" vs "only to do"

Tags: phrases

- He eats, if only to survive.
- He eats only to survive.

  1. Do these two have differences?
  2. And is *if only to* the reduced form of *if it were only to*?

Thanks.

Comment: *if only* is an idiomatic expression, *only* is not. See http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/if-only and other sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> He eats only to survive.

Implies that he has no other reason to eat.

> He eats, if only to survive.

Implies that he hates eating. And if there were a way to survive without eating, he'd consider it.

A better example to get this point across:

> I agreed, if only to shut her up.

Comment: I'm not sure that "I agreed, if only to shut her up" really implies that, if there were a way to shut her up without agreeing, I would have preferred it. Doesn't the phrase rather act to close down discussion on my reasons for agreeing - i.e. "It doesn't matter why I agreed: shutting her up was sufficient justification in itself."

Comment: @Irefuteitthus: I agree. But phrases can act to close down discussion while implying other things.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes.
2. I don't think so.

"He eats only to survive" positively asserts that he eats for no other reason.

"He eats, if only to survive" leaves open the possibility that he has other reasons for eating, but asserts that survival would provide a reason for eating in any event.